# State pattern error in C++ (no suitable constructor)

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, abstract-class, state-pattern

```
class Tool {
public:
    virtual void mouseUp();
    virtual void mouseDown();
    virtual ~Tool();
};

class SelectionTool : public Tool {
    void mouseDown() override {
        std::cout << "SelectionTool icon\n";
    }

    void mouseUp() override {
        std::cout << "Draw a dashed rectangle\n";
    }
};

class BrushTool : public Tool {
    void mouseDown() override {
        std::cout << "BrushTool icon\n";
    }

    void mouseUp() override {
        std::cout << "Draw line\n";
    }
};

class Canvas {
    Tool _currentTool;
public:
    void mouseDown() {
        _currentTool.mouseDown();
    }

    void mouseUp() {
        _currentTool.mouseUp();
    }

    Tool getCurrentTool(){
        return this->_currentTool;
    }

    void setCurrentTool(Tool currentTool) {
        this->_currentTool = currentTool;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    auto george = std::make_unique<Canvas>();
    george->setCurrentTool(std::make_unique<BrushTool>());
    george->mouseDown();
    george->mouseUp();
    return 0;
}
```

No suitable user-defined conversion from "std::unique_ptr<Brush, std::default_delete>" to "Tool" exists.

I am following youtube course where that kind of polymorphism is used in Java and I tried to implement it in C++ but it doesnt work. Whats wrong with that code?

Comment: Does the youtube course on polymorphism involve passing instances of std::unique_ptr? Making the shared pointer "unique" imposes a lot of restrictions on what you can do with it. The smart pointer classes are not interchangable with the underlying object -- if they were, they couldn't do their job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the polymorphism video you were using didn't use smart pointer types.

You can't just use std::shared_ptr<T> as if it were the underlying type. They have get and set interfaces, but they are not a seamless replacement. If they were, they couldn't do their job!

Using std::unique_ptr adds more conditions that you may not want to deal with right now. I'm just going to use std::shared_ptr here.

If you want shared pointers, I'd suggest making a typedef to the shared pointer type and use that everywhere. You can assign std::shared_ptr<derived> to std::shared_ptr<base> similar to the inheritance rules for raw pointers. Just be sure you have a virtual base destructor, which you do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Tool {
public:
    virtual void mouseUp() {}
    virtual void mouseDown() {}
    virtual ~Tool() {}
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Tool> shared_tool_type;

class SelectionTool : public Tool {
    void mouseDown() override {
        std::cout << "SelectionTool icon\n";
    }

    void mouseUp() override {
        std::cout << "Draw a dashed rectangle\n";
    }
};

class BrushTool : public Tool {
    void mouseDown() override {
        std::cout << "BrushTool icon\n";
    }

    void mouseUp() override {
        std::cout << "Draw line\n";
    }
};

class Canvas {
    shared_tool_type _currentTool;
public:
    void mouseDown() {
        _currentTool.get()->mouseDown();
    }

    void mouseUp() {
        _currentTool.get()->mouseUp();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Tool> getCurrentTool() {
        return this->_currentTool;
    }

    void setCurrentTool(shared_tool_type currentTool) {
        this->_currentTool = currentTool;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto george = std::make_shared<Canvas>();
    george->setCurrentTool(std::make_shared<BrushTool>());
    george->mouseDown();
    george->mouseUp();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right unique_ptr was a mistake but using new Selection in main was also resulting in similar error just instead of shared ptr was no conversion from tool to selection. Altough your answer cleared it for me and its working now! Cant give you upvote yet but thanks!

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is used for shared ownership. This is probably not intended in this code and `unique_ptr` would be the correct type.

Comment: Well, it does have getters and setters, and I didn't want to go into std::move, when the question was about inheritance and polymorphism. I find std::unique adds restrictions that aren't helpful for teaching other concepts. Want me to post that code change?

Comment: I don't care if you change your post. I just think it's important to at least mention that there's more to smart pointers than "choosing the one that doesn't complain". I agree that it's easier to show stuff with `shared_ptr` because you can ignore move semantics etc., but at that point, you might as well use a raw pointer. In the end, it's a matter of taste how you teach it, but imho the student should be made aware that there's more to it than meets the eye.